# Is it possible to run AIR player (OSMF) inside a Android app build in java?

Tags: java, android, air

I've an application that used flash player that run in Webview. I would like to switch to AIR player because flash is going out, and also I would like to use RTMPE or HLS, AES for providing video content to my player.

- Do I need to rewrite my app to AIR?
- Is it posible to leave my app as it is and somehow call external AIR player?
- Is it posible to run AIR player in webview?
- Is there any other solution to play RTMPE or HLS AES on android devices?

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing an Android app in java that uses Wowza Media Server and Red5.
My app is in Java and it uses a JAVA RTMP client library (These exist in other languages as well, php, etc.) it can be used in both android and other java platforms.

I use this open source library
http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtmpjavaclient/
Haven't found any issues with it yet using RTMP, I'm not sure if it supports RTMPE, if not, search google for a RTMPE java client.

Hope this helps!